# How to send username / password to a webserver and authenticate?

Tags: android, http, android-studio, https, webserver

I am trying to login to a webserver using the following code.

```
   StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
   URL url = new URL("http://www.mocky.io/v2/568e3d730f0000da3fd1831b");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I have a username and password to login to the server, how do i login using the username/password i have, do i add them to the url before opening a connection or how does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how the server wants to communicate with you. If the server is interested in a GET or a POST. This information should be provided to you by the server side. Then accordingly you can map your method to pass on the username and password. Check [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: The server is using post. How would the code look like to send the username and password to the server in that case?

Comment: Then you dont have to append it to the URL, maybe use JSON or XML to pass it to the other end? Where proper mechanism is employed by the server to read the data you pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley Library directly for your POst request.

```
private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

For more info you can read [Link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/)